# reading files in C. compile error

Tags: c

The code below does not compile. There is a curly line under STDOUT_FILENO in my visual studio, and it does not gives any suggestion on how to correct it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "read_file.h"

void main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   //FILE *fp;
   FILE *fd;
   int num_read;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fd = fopen(file_name, "O_RDONLY");
   if (fd < 0)
     {
           perror("Error while opening the file.\n");

       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   for (;;)
     {
           num_read = fread(fd, ch, sizeof(ch));
           if (num_read < '0')
             {
               perror("Error while reading the file.\n");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }
           if (num_read == 0)
             {
               break;
             }
               fwrite(STDOUT_FILENO, ch, sizeof(ch));
     }

}
```

Comment: Posting the actual compile error would make a bit of sense, no? :)

Comment: Also, `fd = fopen(file_name, "O_RDONLY");` is wrong, `O_RDONLY` is defined elsewhere and used for `open`, not `fopen` (plus `open` wouldn't be looking for the string `"O_RDONLY"`, just `O_RDONLY`). What you probably wanted as the second argument is something like `"r"`. See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).

Comment: It "does not gives any suggestion on how to correct it" because it has no idea what your homework problem is and no idea what you want to do. It's the programmer's job to decide what code to write, not the compiler's.

Answer (score 5):

`STDOUT_FILENO` is defined in `unistd.h`, so you need

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

at the top with the other `#include`s.

**EDIT:** Note that `unistd.h`, and by extension `STDOUT_FILENO` are part of the POSIX standard, which is for Unix systems. Given that you are using Visual Studio, I assume that you are running Windows, and thus can't use POSIX stuff on that machine.

---

That being said, what might be the actual problem is that the arguments you are passing in on that line don't look like they are for `fwrite`, they look like arguments to `write`, which is *also* defined in `unistd.h`.

It looks to me that your original problem was using functions like `open`, `read`, and `write`, which I believe are all POSIX (and thus can't be done on Windows). Then, when you had compilation issues, you tried to replace them with `fopen`, `fread`, and `fwrite` without changing the arguments to match up to the new functions.

As mentioned in a comment, if you want to use `fopen`, `fread`, and `fwrite` (which *can* be used on Windows and are included in `stdio.h`), be sure to use them properly.

Comment: it says cannot open file source file "unistd.h"

Comment: Because if you're using Visual Studio you're not on UNIX, and you won't have it. You're mixing up standard C and UNIX system calls on a Windows compiler, makes no sense.

Comment: I got the code from the class website, and they want me to correct it, is there any other functions that I can use in C to replace that function?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ooh, good point. I'll update the answer to note that.

Comment: You can use the functions you have, just use them properly. There's plenty of documentation around for `fopen()`, `fread()` and the like, just google them.

Answer (score 1):

There's just so much wrong, here:

1. `void main()` - this is not how we define `main()` in C, `main()` returns an `int`.
2. `gets(file_name);` - never use `gets()`, it was always bad, and it's not even part of C any more.
3. `fd = fopen(file_name, "O_RDONLY");` - invalid mode for `fopen()`, `O_RDONLY` (not a string) is used with `open()`
4. `if (fd < 0)` - `fd` is a `FILE *`, you can't compare it with zero, and it'll never be less than zero even if you do, `fopen()` returns `NULL` on failure.
5. `num_read = fread(fd, ch, sizeof(ch));` - totally wrong usage of `fread()`, again you are confusing this with `read()`, and even then, the second argument should be a pointer to a buffer, and you're passing it a single `char`.
6. `if (num_read < '0')` - just, why? This should be `0`, not `'0'`. On an implementation using the ASCII character set, this'll exit your program every time you read less than 48 characters, even if you fixed all the other errors. `fread()` also returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned value, so it'll never be less than `0` unless you're reading more than about 2.1 billion characters and `num_read` overflows, in which case you'll get undefined behavior anyway, in addition to the problems you'll have trying to store over 2.1 billion characters in a single `char`.
7. `fwrite(STDOUT_FILENO, ch, sizeof(ch));` - exact same problem as with `fread()`, you're confusing it with `write()`, and still passing it a single `char`.